# woocommerce subscriptions: how to create subscription page that is not the "shop"?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, subscriptions

im new here and this will be my first question on Stack. So i created a template for WP from scratch and installed woocommerce + subscriptions. my client wants to have their subscription show on a different page than the default woocommerce shop page. 
Thanks guys for any help!

Answer (score 0):

#### With the help woocommerce product shortcode [product id=”99″] we can create all subscriptions page with subscription id.